# Faint black at top of Flutter emulator screen

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I have a problem with my screen The blackness at the top of my screen is not as obvious as in the photo. Is there a reason for this?

[image: Screen]

Comment: Can you post it with your code as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Status bar as transparent

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // transparent status bar
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```